# How quickly can we find a modulated sequence of powers?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, number-systems

How quickly can we find an element of (at least) multiplicative order at least $p$, where $p \in \mathbb{N}$?

The complete question is that we start with a number system of $s$ elements; for example if we are working with the quaternions, $s=4$.  We take all components modulo $m \in \mathbb{N}$.  So, for example, if we are working modulo 5, we would start with a number:

$$16 + 17i + 18j + 19k \equiv 1 + 2i + 3j + 4k \bmod 5$$

Again, I would like to know **how quickly can we find an element of multiplicative order $p$ or greater?**

Essentially, the multiplicative order is the amount of times we multiply a number by itself to get the number 1.

Comment: If you're working in a finite ring (such as your integer quaternions $\mod 5$), you can never find such an element if $p$ is too large.

Comment: @RobertIsrael:  We can assume that $p$ is suitably small.

Comment: A randomly chosen element of a finite group has a good chance of having the maximum order.  So just choosing elements randomly until one works is a good probabilistic method.  Or do you want a deterministic one?

Comment: @RobertIsrael:  Thanks for the randomized algorithm.  I would prefer to get a deterministic one.